# Dynamically forming array of object using given List

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Inputs1

```
var aa = [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"ajai",
      "country":"india",
      "qualification":"BE",
      "age":23
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"aravindh",
      "country":"india",
      "qualification":"BCOM",
      "age":24
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"gopal",
      "country":"china",
      "qualification":"MA",
      "age":23
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"guvaliour",
      "country":"china",
      "qualification":"BE",
      "age":24
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "name":"anavarthan",
      "country":"japan",
      "qualification":"BE",
      "age":25
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "name":"veer",
      "country":"china",
      "qualification":"MA",
      "age":23
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "name":"ramani",
      "country":"india",
      "qualification":"BE",
      "age":23
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "name":"kumar",
      "country":"india",
      "qualification":"MBA",
      "age":23
   }
]
```

Input2

```
 var bb = ['country','age','qualification']
```

Based on the both inputs i want to form the array of object using this required format.

Required Format:

```
[
   {
      "id":"india",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":"23",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":"BE",
                  "children":[

                  ],
                  "dataSet":[
                     {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"ajai",
                        "country":"india",
                        "qualification":"BE",
                        "age":23
                     },
                     {
                        "id":7,
                        "name":"ramani",
                        "country":"india",
                        "qualification":"BE",
                        "age":23
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"MBA",
                  "children":[

                  ],
                  "dataSet":[
                     {
                        "id":8,
                        "name":"kumar",
                        "country":"india",
                        "qualification":"MBA",
                        "age":23
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":"24",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":"BCOM",
                  "children":[

                  ],
                  "dataSet":[
                     {
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"aravindh",
                        "country":"india",
                        "qualification":"BCOM",
                        "age":24
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"china",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":"23",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":"MA",
                  "children":[

                  ],
                  "dataSet":[
                     {
                        "id":6,
                        "name":"veer",
                        "country":"china",
                        "qualification":"MA",
                        "age":23
                     },
                     {
                        "id":3,
                        "name":"gopal",
                        "country":"china",
                        "qualification":"MA",
                        "age":23
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":"24",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":"BE",
                  "children":[

                  ],
                  "dataSet":[
                     {
                        "id":4,
                        "name":"guvaliour",
                        "country":"china",
                        "qualification":"BE",
                        "age":24
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"japan",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":"25",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":"BE",
                  "children":[

                  ],
                  "dataSet":[
                     {
                        "id":5,
                        "name":"anavarthan",
                        "country":"japan",
                        "qualification":"BE",
                        "age":25
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have just tried to form this required format using the input 1 and input 2 but i struggled for a day.Please some one can help me out to solve this issue. I'm using this tree to form a grouping table in Angular 6.This is some what like recursive.

something i have tried like this

```
    var dd=[];
    var aa = [
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"ajai",
         "country":"india",
         "qualification":"BE",
         "age":23
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"aravindh",
         "country":"india",
         "qualification":"BCOM",
         "age":24
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"gopal",
         "country":"china",
         "qualification":"MA",
         "age":23
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "name":"guvaliour",
         "country":"china",
         "qualification":"BE",
         "age":24
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "name":"anavarthan",
         "country":"japan",
         "qualification":"BE",
         "age":25
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "name":"veer",
         "country":"china",
         "qualification":"MA",
         "age":23
      },
      {
         "id":7,
         "name":"ramani",
         "country":"india",
         "qualification":"BE",
         "age":23
      },
      {
         "id":8,
         "name":"kumar",
         "country":"india",
         "qualification":"MBA",
         "age":23
      }
   ];
   var bb = ['country','age','qualification'];
   for(var i=0;i<aa.length;i++){
      for(var j=0;j<bb.length;j++){
        dd.push(this.formingArr(aa[i][bb[j]]))
      }
     }
     console.log(dd);
  }

  formingArr(value){
    let obj={
      id:value,
      children:[],
      dataSet:[]
    }
      return obj;
  }
```

my Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "india",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "BE",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "india",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "BCOM",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "china",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "MA",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "china",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "BE",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "japan",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "BE",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "china",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "MA",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "india",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "BE",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "india",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  },
  {
    "id": "MBA",
    "children": [],
    "dataSet": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Show the code you tried with, it will probably get more people to help you rather than just showing the data and hoping for someone to write the code for you

Comment: I am not sure if i understand correctly, each object in your array looks like a trie. You could probably try to do it in the way similar to trie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested `Map` to create the tree structure, and then iterate that tree recursively to translate those maps to the plain, nested array of objects:

```js
function transform(data, props) {
    // A recursive function to translate nested maps to plain objects/arrays
    const recur = (map, depth) => Array.from(map, ([id, value]) => depth ? {
        id,
        children: recur(value, depth - 1)
    } : {
        id,
        children: [],
        dataSet: Array.from(value.values())
    });

    // First create a nested Map to efficiently create the tree
    let result = new Map;
    for (let obj of data) {
        let map = result;
        for (let prop of props) {
            let key = obj[prop];
            let children = map.get(key);
            if (!children) map.set(key, children = new Map);
            map = children;
        }
        map.set(map.size, obj); // Deepest level is array-like
    }
    // Use recursion to convert the nested Map to the desired object structure
    return recur(result, props.length - 1);
}

// Demo on sample data
var aa = [{"id":1,"name":"ajai","country":"india","qualification":"BE","age":23},{"id":2,"name":"aravindh","country":"india","qualification":"BCOM","age":24},{"id":3,"name":"gopal","country":"china","qualification":"MA","age":23},{"id":4,"name":"guvaliour","country":"china","qualification":"BE","age":24},{"id":5,"name":"anavarthan","country":"japan","qualification":"BE","age":25},{"id":6,"name":"veer","country":"china","qualification":"MA","age":23},{"id":7,"name":"ramani","country":"india","qualification":"BE","age":23},{"id":8,"name":"kumar","country":"india","qualification":"MBA","age":23}];

var bb = ['country','age','qualification']

console.log(transform(aa, bb));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var aa = [{"id":1,"name":"ajai","country":"india","qualification":"BE","age":23},{"id":2,"name":"aravindh","country":"india","qualification":"BCOM","age":24},{"id":3,"name":"gopal","country":"china","qualification":"MA","age":23},{"id":4,"name":"guvaliour","country":"china","qualification":"BE","age":24},{"id":5,"name":"anavarthan","country":"japan","qualification":"BE","age":25},{"id":6,"name":"veer","country":"china","qualification":"MA","age":23},{"id":7,"name":"ramani","country":"india","qualification":"BE","age":23},{"id":8,"name":"kumar","country":"india","qualification":"MBA","age":23}];

  var bb=[];
    var cc = ['country','age','qualification'];
    for(var i=0;i<=aa.length-1;i++){
      cc.reduce((acc,ele,index)=>{
        let obj={
          id: ele,
          name: aa[i][ele],
          children:[],
          dataSet: []
        }
        let pos = acc.map(ele=>ele.name).indexOf(aa[i][ele]);
        let ind = 0;
        if(pos == -1){
         acc.push(obj);
         ind = acc.length-1 < 0 ? 0 : acc.length-1;
        }else{
         ind=pos;
        }
        return acc[ind]['children'];
      },bb)
    }
    console.log(bb)
```